# Finding a specific number in a random array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Below is the code I've written to find the largest and smallest number in an array of 100 integers(which are random).

My question is for the user to enter a number and find the location of the number the user entered. For example: "The number 230 was found at array location 34" or something like that.

How do I go about this question? My attempt looks something like

```
cout << "Enter #: ";
cin >> Input;
if(1){
for (int i = 0; i < 100 : i++){
if (Input == arr[i]
cout << "Location: " << i << endl;
} else
cout << "Input was not found ";



#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int small, big;
    int arr[100];

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    big = small = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > big) {
            big = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < small) { // compares smallest value with current element
            small = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple loop will be more elegant and readable

Comment: not sure what makes you believe you are using or have to use a recursive function?

Comment: I was asking what ways to answer the question? recursive or not. Or can i just simply add that bit to the end of the code to find the location of a particular number?

Comment: It is never absolutely necessary to use a recursive function. Any recursive function can be transformed into a non-recursive function (but it may need dynamic allocation for variables that originally had automatic storage duration)

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question, hope it's clearer now

Comment: seems to me that the 'main' code was given to you are you are being asked to add a user interaction. The code you add needs to go inside the 'main ' function. It cant just free float as you seem to have it. I assume you are getting huge compile errors at the moent

Comment: You will get much better answers if you will wait for an hour or two before marking one a "the" answer.

Comment: Duly noted. I'm pretty new to the site

Comment: Yes I was getting huge errors :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple (and not ideal) solution is to loop over the array until the desired number is found. Something along the lines of:

```
const int N = 100;
int arr[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 1000;
}

// Number to search for
int target = 11;

// Single loop searching for target
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == target) {
        index = i;
        break; // break when target found
    }
}

if (index != -1) {
    cout << "Found at " << index << "\n";
}
else {
    cout << "Not Found\n";
}
```

However, you should use a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) whenever possible instead of an array. One benefit of using a vector is the ability to use the standard library [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec;

    // fill vec with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int random_number = rand() % 1000;
        vec.push_back(random_number); // adds random_number to end of vec
    }

    // Number we are searching for
    int target = 7;

    // find an iterator pointing to target if it exists
    //   else it will be vec.end()
    auto it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target);

    if (it != vec.end()) {
        // find distance of it from beggining of vector
        // i.e. vec[index] == target
        int index = distance(vec.begin(), it);
        cout << "Found " << target << " at " << index << "\n";
    }
    else {
         cout << "Not Found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't learnt vector in class yet, hence I can't use it. Thank you for the loop

Comment: No problem. If you are interested you can look ahead at using vectors.